# regular expression in java-script to accept only numbers from 0-9 hyphen and alphabet with no space

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, regex, web

i have try lot but fail any one if give such regular expression give also detail 
 
**Different Possibility are**

```
12-er-34
```

or it may be like

```
woc-ii-98
```

expression must contain numeric number but its not necessary to take hyphen in every expression.i need this to onblur function of input when user enter text and go to other if the text match the regular expression its ok else alert text not allowd

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: What is up with the 3 tags JS, PHP, ASP.NET? Which one are you using this in? (Not that it matter much, though)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}\-[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\-[0-9]{2})
```

I'm no regex expert but it seems to work in the testing tool i have :)